# PCY algorithm in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, fpgrowth

so I am having a code here with FPGrowth library in Pyspark

[image]

What Im trying to do here is to create the freqItemsets and assocationRules manually to understand better about the PCY(Park-Chen-Yu) algorithm, can someone help ?

Please note we can only use Pyspark and anything relate to Data Mining, that means we are not allow to use library like pandas and so on.

Comment: Hi there, please update your post! no images are allowed cause they can't reproduced!

Comment: Is it a job or college question ?

Comment: Hello! It looks like you've shared an image to illustrate your issue, which is a good start. To increase your chances of getting the help you need, could you please also add a written description? Explaining in text what the problem is, any specific errors shown in the image, and what you've attempted to solve it can greatly help others understand and assist you. Remember, the more effort you put into articulating your question, the more likely you are to receive the assistance you're looking for. Thanks! :)